# Netbeans ' and " while using CSS style

Tags: html, css, netbeans

I'm trying to make a simple HTML5/JS app. and having an issue while writing code in index.html.
Yesterday when using style attribute the property: value were in a single quote (apostrophe). but today the same thing is in double quotes.
I have searched the web but didn't find a solution.

```
    <tr style='width: auto'>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style='width: 10%'></td>
                <td style='width: 10%'></td>
                <td style=""></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style=""></td>
            </tr>
```

Using Netbeans 8.2

This happens automatically when I press = equal key

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: And normally, use `"` in attributes in `html`

Comment: @Swellar. Trying to ask that is there something wrong with NetBeans setting which automatically set single or double quotes when I press = after style attribute

Comment: I think Intellisense goes for double quotes rather that single quote. And unfortunately this is off-topic in SO as you are asking for a behavior of an IDE

Comment: Thank You @Swellar. I know this is Off-topic so please can you provide me a link where I can ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

After some more efforts searching on the web. I found out a solution here on StackOverflow.

[How to force netbeans html autocompletion to use double quotes instead of single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263616/how-to-force-netbeans-html-autocompletion-to-use-double-quotes-instead-of-single)
Kindly see @Dmitry's answer and the link provided by him.
which is this
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228535 (Answer at the bottom)

ANSWER: 
Use a Single quote or Double Quote as per your need. and NetBeans will automatically save your preferences after a while.

Thank SOF Family